# Split string by comma, but not escaped in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I wrote code that splits a string by comma:

```
"Keyword,slug,description".split(',');
```

Which results in an array like `["Keyword", "slug", "description"]`

This worked fine for awhile, until someone needed a comma in their description.

I know I can replace `split` with `match` and use a regular expression, but the only regular expression I can come up with involves a negative lookbehind, like this:

```
"Keyword,slug,description".match(/(?<!\\),/);
```

Unfortunately JavaScript doesn't support lookbehinds.

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Is your string _always_ `keyword,slug,description` where the `keyword` and `slug` _never_ have commas?  So you only need to find the first two commas, everything after that is the description, no matter what characters it contains?

Comment: how will you be able to tell a comma-as-separator from comma-as-regular-char? `"splitme,comma,separated,splitme"` -> `["splitme", "comma,separated","splitme"]` isn't exactly very obvious. Perhaps you should fix whatever's generating this CSV string in the first place, and use something more robust as the encoding method, like json.

Comment: can you not escape every instance of description before its used for the split?

Comment: @JamesThorpe Yes, it will always be keyword,slug,description. Keyword and slug shouldn't have commas, but the description might.

Comment: Try [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/tnnx05vk/1/).

Comment: @MarcB I want to allow people to escape their own description. So if they do `Planes\, Trains\, and Automobiles' and it won't split those commas

Comment: you shouldn't be requiring users to do that sort of thing.... that's bad design, overall.

Comment: @MarcB Giving them the option to include commas in their description is the requirement. I'm looking for the best way to do that. What do you recommend?

Comment: i would quote any segments with commas. oh, and `"a\,b"==="a,b"`, so that's not going to work...

Comment: Best way to do it is to change the output so you do not need to do a split in the first place.

Comment: you can cheat with unicode: `"Keyword,slug\\,description".split("\\,").join("❟").split(",")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So use match instead of split

```
"Keyword,slug,description".match(/([^,]+),([^,]+),(.*)/);
```

will result in

```
["Keyword,slug,description", "Keyword", "slug", "description"]
```

There are other ways to write the regular expression, just picked something quick.

Comment: That seems to result in an array with 1 item in it: ["Keyword,slug,description"]

Comment: whoops, some reason I added a g flag...edited it out

Comment: This will work for me. I will just have to ignore the first item in the array. Thank you

Comment: Or you can always use `match(...).splice(1,3)` to make it act like your original.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a not-so-nice way, but the general principle can come in handy:

```
"keyword,slug,foo\\,bar"
.replace( '\\,', '{COMMA}' )
.split(',')
.map(function(v){return v.replace('{COMMA}',',')})
```

Comment: I didn't accept this answer, but this was a cool solution. Thank you

Comment: That's allright - in your case the other answer is better, but I thought I'd show the approach. Thanks for the upvote!

Answer (score 0):

If you manually give the string as the input, then you can escape the comma via HTML entity.

```
var message = 'This is a message with some comma(,) and (,) ';
message = message.replaceAll(",", "&#x2c;");
var params = 'title=Confirm,message='+message+'position=middle';
showAlert(params);
```

Now regular .split method will work

```
function showAlert(params) {
  params = params.split(","); 
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If not considered special characters, you can use a simple solution like:

```js
'a,b\\,c,d'.split(/\b,/); // => ['a', 'b\\,c', 'd']
```

If considered, you can use a more complex solution like:

```js
'a,b!\\,c,d'.split(/\\,/)
    .map(function (s) { return s.split(','); })
    .reduce(function (result, arr) {
        return [].concat(result.slice(0, -1)).concat([result.slice(-1)[0], arr[0]].filter(x => x).join('\\,')).concat(arr.slice(1));
    }, []); // => ['a', 'b!\\,c', 'd']
```